# Improve quality of image bars

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

Do you know how to make the vertical bars in this image more visible? Especially on the right side. I'd like to have the vertical bars more sharp and outstanding from the background)? I tried using the sharpening tool in photoshop, but that wasn't sufficient.

In the last resort, I am thinking to draw new vertical elements over the image. But that would be tedious and something I'd like to avoid.[image]

EDIT: This is the best result so far. Please note that the code **does not** match.
[image]

Comment: Barcodes need to be scannable... so.... really redrawing them to be *precise* is best if you can't simply use an online barcode generator. And redrawing *may* result in a faulty code as well, even if you are careful to match each line width and each space -- they all actually *mean* something to the scanner.

Comment: Hi Nadia, if you need it to be scannable I would definitely get the sku information (numbers) and use a generator. Otherwise, have you tried using levels in photoshop?

Comment: The contrast between the bars and the background must be black on white—even light-coloured backgrounds are discouraged. As for the bars/spaces they are both either one or two units wide and alternate, black, white, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The issue is that I want to obtain the sku information from the image. I just tried levels in photoshop and that helped a lot. However, on the righ part t - where the two thick bars are - tend to glue with eachoter. I believe that makes it more difficult to read the image.

Comment: Can I ask you to confirm that you are trying to recover the image for aesthetic purposes and not to make it (or similar ones) scannable?  Your question leaves this open and many people assume you do want to correctly recover this 1 scan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I must be nuts but I redrew it. Now I get:

**710024577829**

That is so similar to my other answer I have to think that the first answer (G10024577829) is probably right, and I simply didn't redraw it accurately enough)

[image]

Comment: Just an idea , but the original can be salvaged quite  well with  a vertical min filter.

Comment: Thanks mayersdesign. Due to your help, I made it work !

Comment: Your original answer was correct. If you looked at the Code 39 standard, you'd see that the original image, as well as this one, are both backwards. However, if you go and manually work out the code, you'll get the code starting with G, not 7

Answer (score 7):

This is a contrast issue more than a sharpness issue. Try

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for Auto Contrast or `Image → Auto Contrast`.
- or `Image → Adjustments → Black & White` to get specific control.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The Auto Contrast definitely helped. It's true that it primairily is a contrast issue. However, I do believe that the right part of the image is somewhat blurry, and makes it impossible to retrieve the barcode for now.

Answer (score 4):

Using the work by mayersdesign, this was easy. This *is* Code 39. The image is backwards/upside-down. Once you turn the image 180 degrees, you can see the proper Code 39 headers. (The beginning is different from the end.)
[image]

[image: Code 39 barcode image]

Comment: Thanks, David. I upvoted, since I have the answer already. You are totally right!

Comment: Well done! It's like Sherlock Holmes in this thread haha

Comment: I manually verified the first half before I saw the answer that @mayersdesign had posted was correct.

Comment: Here's the site I used to verify:
https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/Code39FullASCII?data=G100245777829

Answer (score 3):

I cleaned it up to a degree using Perspective transform, Curves, Dust & Scratches (filter) and Unsharp mask. This useful website: https://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/ then read the code as:

**G10024577829**

No idea if that's right, but I tried another cleanup of the same image and it read the same, so I am quite confident.

[image]

The little graphic appears to indicate the whole image is being used...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort, mayersdesign. I got the same number after some attempts on photoshop. However, this number doesn't read the right darker part of the image (the two thick bars)

Comment: I just updated the image above. I manually separated those two black bars and it reads the same. I will add the screenshot which appears to show it is reading the whole code. I can't prove it IS of course.

Comment: You can ofcourse generate the barcode (I just did it). Then, you easily notice they are unfortunately not the same.

Comment: Hi Nadia, I tried that but I do not know the format of the barcode. What is it?

Comment: I believe it is code39

Comment: Hmmm. Even the beginning of the code looks different in code39. I just cleaned it up more manually on the right (see above), and still cannot get a different result. Let me know how you get on solving it.